# How to change form property value from another form(formBorderStyle, etc)? C# and windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

This is sample code

```
Form 1
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        }

        private void btnAdmin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm = new Form2();
            frm.Show();
        }
}
```

Form 1 open form 2 which ask admin password.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(textBox1.Text == "123")
            {
                Setting frm = new Setting();
                frm.Show();
                this.Close();
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have entered wrong password.");
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

now, if you entered right password, it will take to form 3 which is a setting menu for form 1.

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 frm = new Form1();
            frm.Show();

            if (fullscreenYes.Checked == true)
            {
                frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            }

            if (fullscreenYes.Checked == false)
            {
                frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            }

            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

so now, i want to use radio button change FormBorderStyle of form 1 from form 3 but it doesn't work because my current code just opens a new Form1 and apply that setting to newly opened form 1 and leaving previously opened Form 1 opened.
I end up having 2 form 1 opened like this. How do I change form 1 property directly from form 3 without having 2 form 1 opened? I've been at this for hours but can't figure it out. Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for manipulating an existing instance of a form so you can modify or set stuff, use `OpenForms.OfType`

quick sample:

```
var frm1 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Single();

//set some stuff
frm1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

frm1.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve your goal.

**#1 Give access to Form3 from accessing Form1 through its constructor**

```
private Form1 _owner;
public Form3(Form1 owner)
{
   owner = _owner;
}

void DoSomethingToForm1()
{
    // do something.. _owner.Prop = ?;
}
```

Then call Form3 from Form1

```
new Form3(this).Show();
```

**#2 Use singleton pattern**

```
private static object _lockObj = new object();
private static Form1 _instance = new Form1();

public static Form1 Instance 
{
   lock(_lockObj)
   {
      get
      {
         if(_instance == null || _instance.IsDisposed) _instance = new Form1();
         return _instance;
      }
    }
 }
```

Then call Form1 from Form3

```
var f = Form1.Instance;
// do something to form1
```

Comment: not working.. if you see my code, it's form 1 calling form 2 while form 1 is still opening. then form 2 calls form 3 and close itself. it's done while form 1 is still opened in the back. finally, when form 3 opens, setting suppose to change property of form 1 while form 1 is still open and close itself(form3) when it's done. 1st method doesn't work because it only consider relation between form 1 and 3 and not counting form 2. 2nd method, do i have to use reference or something? it's all red lined.

Comment: also, if I skip form3 and just make panel on form1 and make form2 to open that secret menu panel on form 1, i get this error saying System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

_owner was null.